# How to create Setpin and Clearpin in C for microcontroller?

Tags: c, arduino, avr, atmelstudio

I am relatively new in programming µC in C and have previously always used the arduino IDE. I would like to create a function that sets and clears a pin. I tried this

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define F_CPU 16000000UL

void set_led(int poort,int pin){
    poort |= (1<<pin);
    //PORTB |= (1<<pin); <-- this works
}
void clear_led(int poort,int pin){
    poort &= ~(1<<pin);

}

int main(void)
{
    DDRD = 0xff;
    PORTD = 0x00;
    while(1)
    {
        set_led(PORTD,PD7);
        _delay_ms(500);
        clear_led(PORTD,PD7);
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}
```

The pin variable works like it should but when I implement the poort variable the led does not blink anymore. Does someone know how to fix this?
I use eclipse(AVR) on manjaro and the controller is an arduino nano.

Comment: `PORTB` is probably `define`d something like this: `*(volatile int *)0x<address>`.  `int poort` is at a different address so it cannot manipulate the value at `PORTB`.

Comment: You are aware that function parameters in C are passed by value? Any changes you make to `poort` are not copied back into `PORTD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C is pass by value only the local variable is changed.

You could either use macros:

```
#define SET_LED(POORT, PIN) ((POORT) |= (1<<(PIN)))
```

or pass the variable as pointer:

```
void set_led(volatile uint8_t *poort, int pin)
{
    *poort |= (1<<pin);
}
```

and call it with `set_led(&port, pin);` for example.

The type `int` is probably wrong and should be `volatile uint8_t`.